# How do different file types differ?

Tags: file, unix, jpeg, file-type

So far, I understood:

- Files have some information in their 'headers' which programs use to detect the file type.

  1. Is it always true? If so how can I see the header?

     > Is it the only way of defining a file's type?
  2. Is there a way to manually create an empty file (at least in Linux) with no headers at all?
  3. If so, can I manually write its header and create a simple 'jpg' file

Answer (score 1):

1. No, files simply have bytes and some metadata like a filename, permissions, last modified time. The format of those bytes is completely free and open without convention. Certainly some file types like jpegs,gifs,audio and video files have headers specified in their formats. Viewing a header depends completely on the format involved. They will normally be comprised of byte codes meaningless to the human eye so some software would normally be required to decode and view them.
2. yes.

   touch emptyFile
3. Sounds painful. Use a library to write a jpeg. Headers are not necessarily easy to create. Someone else has done this hard work for you so I'd use it.

Answer (score 0):

A file is nothing more than a sequence of bytes, and it has no default, internal structure. It is an abstraction made by the OS to make it more convenient to store and manipulate data.

Files may represent different types of things like images, videos, audio and plain text, so these need to be *interpreted* in a certain way in order to interact with their contents. For instance; an image is opened in an image viewer, a PDF document is opened in a PDF viewer; an audio file is opened in a media player. That doesn't mean you cannot open an image in a text editor - the file's contents will only be interpreted differently.

The closest thing to file *metadata* in UNIX and Linux is the [inode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inode) - which stores information about files, but are not part of the files themselves - and the files's [magic number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_format#Magic_number). Use `stat` to inspect the inode and use `file` to determine its type (sometimes based on its magic number).

Also check out `man file` for more information about file types.